# Add subcollection to Firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple web chat app and the schema for Firestore looks likee the following

```
- chats (collection)
   - username
      - chats (collection)
         - ohterUsername
            - lastMessage: "hey"
            - lastUpdated: timestamp
            - username: otherUsername

            - messages (collection)
               - createdAt: timestamp
               - message: "hey"
               - from: username
               - to: otherUsername
```

I added two fields `lastUpdated, lastMessage` to keep track of activity so that I will order chat rooms accordingly for the user.

```
            await firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection("chats")
            .doc(user.displayName)
            .collection("chats")
            .orderBy("lastUpdated", "desc")
            .limit(1)
            .get()
            .then(function (snapshot) {
              console.log(snapshot.docs);
              if (snapshot.docs.length > 0) {
                snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                    const data = doc.data();
                    // get the user object who last messaged
                    console.log(data); 

                    // check if messages subcollection exists for this user,
                    // if yes, then retrieve the messages  
                    // if not, create it as empty collection so that it will be populated 
                    // when users exchange messages
                    firebase
                    .firestore()
                    .collection("chats")
                    .doc(user.displayName)
                    .collection("chats")
                    .doc(doc.data().username)
                    .collection("messages")
                    .orderBy("createdAt")
                    .get()
                    .then((snapshot) => {
                      snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                        const data = doc.data();
                        console.log(data);
                      });
                    });
                });
            } else {
              console.log("nothing");
            }
```

For this user, there is no  `messages` subcollection, and my question is how do I add it as an empty collection so that it will be populated after user sends a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to be create an empty sub-collection, it's an anti-pattern.

Instead, when a new messge is sent, do

```js
await firestore
  .collection('chats')
  .doc(user.displayName)
  .collection('chats')
  .doc(recipient.displayName)
  .colleciton('messages')
  .add(messageData) // presuming message data contains document data for message
```

> You can check the documentation on the [`add` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#add) here.

This will create a new collection and generate it's first document at the same time. This also helps with querying, where you could check straight away, whether the collection even exists.

---

Also this is outside of the scope of the question / answer. But I wouldn't exactly recommend saving messages in this manner because

1. [Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) is better suited for saving user-generated content, especially if you plan on allowing users to send anything else than only a plaintext message in near future.
2. If you decide to stick to firestore, the three nested sub-collections seem pretty redundant, the `chats -> {userId} -> chats -> {recipientId} -> messages -> {messageId}` in specific. Instead you could structure the data based on the recipient id as separate documents, i.e.

   ```js
   - chats/{userId}
      - messages/{recipientId}: {
          ...messageData
        }
   ```

   Your proposed data structure would only make sense if the user could open multiple chatrooms with the same user.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it is what I was looking for! I have also been thinking to storing the chat data in Firebase Storage, but I do not see any resources that explain how to do it, it is mentioned it is only for images and files. Maybe you have some resources?

Answer (score 1):

collections/sub-collections aren't a concrete resource in Cloud Firestore, but just an implicit method to organize documents and the indexes created for those documents. In other words, there isn't such a thing as an empty collection or sub-collection. You'd have to create a 'sample' or 'dummy' document for the collection to exist.

you can just create the subCollection with a placeholder document and then in your front end filter out that document it should be easy as it is the first `docs[0]`

> learn more https://groups.google.com/g/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/c/o3tUFJpPYKc?pli=1